# why my all js file not working in angular 4

Tags: angular

[image]

I have tried running the following `npm install` but it doesn't fix anything.

```
npm install jquery --save 
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

I have added

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "`../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js"],
```

in .angular-cli.json file.

The materialize CSS is working but the animation and the JS that require to do the animation is not working ...

Comment: Try to put jquery first in that list. As angular loads them in order it is good to place jquery first

Comment: thank you buddy! its now working :)